# about C++ pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have just started to practice c++ and I am stuck at one point.
I have a Node class and the class has a constructor like this:

```
class Node
{
    public:
          Node(std::string,Node *,int,int,int,int);
    private:
          std::string state;
          Node* parent_node;
          int total_cost;
          int path_cost;
          int heuristic_cost;
          int depth;  
}

Node::Node(std::string state,Node *parent_node,int path_cost,int heuristic_cost,int total_cost,int depth)
{
    this->state=state;
    this->parent_node=parent_node;
    this->path_cost=path_cost;
    this->heuristic_cost=heuristic_cost;
    this->total_cost=total_cost;
    this->depth=depth;
}
```

Everything works ok so far, but I can not create a Node object with a NULL parent_node.
I have tried this:

```
Node *n = new Node("state name",NULL,0,15,20,1);
```

I have also tried creating a new object and assigning it as parent_node, but no success either.

```
Node *temp = new Node();
Node *n = new Node("state name",temp,0,15,20,1);
```

I am doing something wrong with the pointer but I don't know what I am missing. I get a compile error which says no matching function call.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exact error message are you getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your `constructor public`?

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node(std::string,Node *,int,int,int,int);
private:
    std::string state;
    Node* parent_node;
    int total_cost;
    int path_cost;
    int heuristic_cost;
    int depth;  
};
```

---

Also, don't forget the semicolon after `Node` declaration, this is not Java ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's normal to specify `0` for a null pointer value, instead of `NULL` (`NULL` is a macro used for C which, depending on how the macro is defined, might not work well with C++).

Also, I don't like to see `std::string` as a parameter type. I'd prefer to see either `const char*`, or `const std::string&`.

Also `Node* node = new Node();` will produce that compiler error, because when you declare a non-default constructor then you hide the default constructor (where by 'default constructor' I mean the constructor which takes no parameters). If you want to support `new Node();` then you need to explicitly declare the default constructor (and, define how it's implemented.)

Comment: `NULL` is typically `#defined` to a plain `0` in C++ and to `((void*)0)` in C.

Comment: Yes, and if it were defined as `((void*)0)` that wouldn't work with C++. The OP didn't say what it's defined as in his code.

Comment: You should never define it yourself. Use the definitions provided in the standard headers.

Comment: Stroustrup prefers to avoid using NULL: http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#null

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me on GCC-4 on Mac OS X, after correcting the typos and implementing a Node::Node() constructor. It'd probably be helpful if you edited your question to include all the code to your test program, as well as the actual error messages you're getting when you compile.

Comment: hi, sorry but the compiler gives the error message in turkish, which does not make any sense to me. someone translated the error messages into turkish very poorly.

Comment: Okay, but you can read English, right? Just install a stock version of GCC, and try reading that error message.

Answer (score 0):

The following compiles fine for me:

```
// Added this.
#include <string>


class Node
{    public:
          Node(std::string,Node *,int,int,int,int);
    private:
          std::string state;
          Node* parent_node;
          int total_cost;
          int path_cost;
          int heuristic_cost;
          int depth;
}; // Added semicolon here

Node::Node(std::string state,Node *parent_node,
           int path_cost,int heuristic_cost,int total_cost,int depth)
{
        this->state=state;
        this->parent_node=parent_node;
        this->path_cost=path_cost;
        this->heuristic_cost=heuristic_cost;
        this->total_cost=total_cost;
        this->depth=depth;
}

// Put code inside main.
int main()
{
    Node *n = new Node("state name",NULL,0,15,20,1);
}
```